# Preprocessor definitions in code and project properties

Tags: visual-c++

I have simple console application in which I must set preprocessor definition `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`. According to my understanding I can set it my code right after `#include "stdafx.h"` by puting line `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` or in `Project Properties -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions`. If I do first way I still have problems in code if I do second way - it solves my problem. Why I can't define `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` in source code?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this problem is really on the project properties, causing it to be used globally as a compiler flag. If you use the `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` in a file, only that file will have that warning suppressed.